# Terraform custom provider GPG issue

Tags: go, terraform, gnupg

hope you're doing well.

I'm writing an API using in Go that can works similarly to the [terraform provider protocol](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html)

So I already have two endpoints working on my local machine over HTTPS:

- `https://myapi:9000/v1/provider/:namespace/:type/versions`
- `https://myapi:9000/v1/provider/:namespace/:type/:version/download/:os/:arch`

Let's say for example these full endpoint:

- `https://myapi:9000/v1/provider/myprovider/custom/versions`
- `https://myapi:9000/v1/provider/myprovider/custom/0.1.0/download/linux/amd64`

So I have the next .tf.json file:

```json
{
    "module": {
        "linux": {
            "source": "myapi:9000/v1/module/mymodule/custom",
            "version": "0.1.2"
        }
    }
}
```

That uses this two files

1. provider.tf.json

```json
provider "mycustomprovider" {
    username = "abc"
    password = "def"
    host = "yjk"
}
```

2. versions.tf.json

```json
terraform {
    required_providers {
        mycustomprovider = {
            source: "myapi:9000/v1/myprovider/custom",
            version: "0.1.0"
        }
    }
    required_version = ">=1.0.2"
}
```

Then I simply run: `terraform init` to get my assets.

So, when I'm getting my custom module, that works fine.
Output (module download):

```
Initializing modules...
Downloading myapi:9000/mymodule/custom/gnu 0.1.2 for linux...
- linux in .terraform/modules/linux

Initializing the backend...
```

But when I'm getting my provdier I have this error:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding myapi:9000:9000/myprovider/custom versions matching "0.1.0"...
- Installing myapi:9000:9000/myprovider/custom v0.1.0...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing myapi:9000/myprovider/custom v0.1.0: error checking signature:
│ openpgp: invalid data: tag byte does not have MSB set
```

So, my provider `versions` endpoint is working. That's why terraform is able to recognize the version of my provider.

The problem should be on my `download` endpoint.

Before talking about this endpoint I want to add some context, I'm running a S3 client using [localstack](https://localstack.cloud/) and exposing it through [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). These two things work and I able to upload or download files without problem.

Terraform custom providers should have three files (as I understand):

1. the provider in zip format (like in their example)
2. a `provider_SHA256SUMS` file with the shasums of each provider zip file (in this case I'm only have one)
3. a `provider_SHA256SUMS.sig` that is uses to recognize the integrity of the `provider_SHA256SUMS` file.

So to get these files I'm running these commands:

**provider_SHA256SUMS**

```
$ sha256sum 0.1.0.zip > 0.1.0_SHA256SUMS
```

**provider_SHA256SUMS**

```
$ gpg --gen-key # generating a new key
$ gpg --armor --output 0.1.0_SHA256SUMS.sig --detach-sig 0.1.0_SHA256SUMS
```

The response with my endpoint is something like this. **(the gpg info is just sample data, no real warning here.)**

```json
{
  "protocols": [
    "5.0"
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "arch": "amd64",
  "filename": "0.1.0.zip",
  "download_url": "https://d4f6-186-84-89-138.ngrok.io/terraform/v1/providers/myprovider/custom/0.1.0.zip",
  "shasums_url": "https://d4f6-186-84-89-138.ngrok.io/terraform/v1/providers/myprovider/custom/0.1.0_SHA256SUMS",
  "shasums_signature_url": "https://d4f6-186-84-89-138.ngrok.io/terraform/v1/providers/myprovider/custom/0.1.0_SHA256SUMS.sig",
  "shasum": "1dd61b508aad0d65b32c71159775e409fd618adc5ba945cc2eebb42f29e085d3",
  "signing_keys": {
    "gpg_public_keys": [
      {
        "key_id": "9F21EA3C1C9F793C",
        "ascii_armor": "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n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\nCZWzoNTMkeFkob1UkxIe+Q==\n=wZDI\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `shasum` prop in the response should be a shasum corresponding to the provider zip file, it can also be found inside the `provider_SHA256SUMS` file.

To get the `key_id` and `ascii_armor` props I'm running this commands:

```sh
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long ## key_id
$ gpg --armor --export <MY_KEYID> > public.gpg ## export to public key to base64
$ cat public.gpg | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g' ## one-lined ascii_armor
```

**Short Question**

What am I doing wrong with the gpg key to get this error? Am I lacking of steps, or doing everything wrong?

`openpgp: invalid data: tag byte does not have MSB set`

**----Update----**

**This is how I'm building the response in Go:**

*I'm not putting the full code because I belive that the problem is with the `KeyID` and `ASCIIArmor` atributes.*

*As you can see: `Shasum`, `KeyID` and `ASCIIArmor` are hardcoded.*

```golang
response := ProviderDownloadResponse{
        Protocols:           protocols,
        Os:                  os,
        Arch:                arch,
        Filename:            filename,
        DownloadURL:         downloadURL,
        ShasumsURL:          SHASUMsURL,
        ShasumsSignatureURL: SHASUMSSignatureURL,
        Shasum:              "1dd61b508aad0d65b32c71159775e409fd618adc5ba945cc2eebb42f29e085d3",
        SigningKeys: SigningKeys{
            GpgPublicKeys: []GPGPublicKey{
                {
                    KeyID:      "9F21EA3C1C9F793C",
                    ASCIIArmor: "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n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\nCZWzoNTMkeFkob1UkxIe+Q==\n=wZDI\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----",
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x/crypto/openpgp` that is used by terraform does not support reading armored messages, see [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29082#issuecomment-453340235), this is where the error comes from.

[`shasums_signature_url`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/provider-registry-protocol.html#shasums_signature_url) filed doc mentions:

> binary, detached GPG signature

Also, see [Manually preparing a release doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/registry/providers/publishing.html#manually-preparing-a-release)

> which is a valid GPG binary (not ASCII armored) signature

So you should try signing without `--armor` flag.

Comment: Hi @Artem you were right, the signing should be without the '--armor' tag and now is working like a charm... I've been having this problem for a couple of days and now is working. Thank you very much.